# Authenticate with OneDrive SDK in a c# console project

Tags: c#, console-application, onedrive

I'm trying to create a program that will download all my OneNote files from OneDrive. But when I try to authenticate using `msaAuthenticationProvider` a white window appears and then nothing happens. I think the window is supposed to be the Microsoft login, but nothing appears in it.

Here's my code:

```
string[] scopes = new string[] {
    "onedrive.readonly",
    "wl.signin"
};
var msaAuthenticationProvider = new MsaAuthenticationProvider(
    clientId,
    returnURL,
    scopes);

await msaAuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateUserAsync();
var client = new OneDriveClient(URL, msaAuthenticationProvider);
```

It gets to the AuthenticateUserAsync method, then the window apperas, and after that nothing happens.
I'm also not sure what the returnURL is supposed to be because all examples where either for an app version or just said return URL without giving any examples.

Answer (score 1):

sorry for the delay. Have you tried this method:

```
msaAuthenticationProvider.RestoreMostRecentFromCacheOrAuthenticateUserAsync();
```

Edit : If the last known connection token is usable, this method can be used to authenticate the user without prompt it. So, this restore the last authentication cache if it can or prompt the user to give his login and password. This can replace the already used AuthenticateUserAsync method. I had the same issue and this method solved it.

Edit 2 : The OneDrive SDK documentation is very poor, I found this myself fiercely as I found that you can get the connection token (to save it for example) and inject it when you need like that in an async task :

```
        if (_OneDriveCacheBlob == null)
        {
            bool needtosaveblob = true;
            _OneDriveCacheBlob = null;
            CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();
            _OneDriveCacheBlob = GetUser(CurrentUserName).OneDriveAuthProviderBlob;

            if (_OneDriveCacheBlob != null)
            {
                cc.InitializeCacheFromBlob(_OneDriveCacheBlob);
                needtosaveblob = false;
            }
            MsaAuthenticationProvider msaAuthProvider = new MsaAuthenticationProvider(OneDriveClass.clientId, OneDriveClass.returnUrl, scopes, cc);

            int timeout = 15;
            _ = Task.Run(() => WaitForODConnection(msaAuthProvider));                
            while (!WaitForODConnectionExecuted)
            {
                if (timeout <= 0)
                    break;

                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                timeout -= 1;
            }
            WaitForODConnectionExecuted = false;

            if (timeout <= 0)
            {
                // Request for reconnection to OneDrive because of invalid Blob                    
                await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () =>
                {
                    //This method requests a new login by a simple msaAuthProvider.AuthenticateUserAsync() call from a new instance of MsaAuthenticationProvider and a new instance of CredentialCache.
                    //ChangeOneDriveAccount(); 
                });
            }
            else
            {
                _OneDriveClient = new OneDriveClient(OneDriveClass.basUrl, msaAuthProvider);
            }

            string accessToken = msaAuthProvider.CurrentAccountSession.AccessToken;
            JObject json = await GetUserInfos(msaAuthProvider.CurrentAccountSession.AccessToken);
            if (json != null)
            {
                // If you need
                oneDriveUserName = json["name"].ToString();
                oneDriveEmail = json["emails"]["account"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                //Unable to get OneDrive user informations;                    
            }

            if (needtosaveblob)
            {
                _OneDriveCacheBlob = cc.GetCacheBlob();
                //You can save _OneDriveCacheBlob to reuse it later;
            }
        }
```

To get the user infos :

```
/// <summary>
    /// Return User informations as a JObject. To get username and email, if return isn't null :
    /// username = json["name"].ToString();
    /// email = json["emails"]["account"].ToString();
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="accessToken">accesstoken of Onedrive account</param>
    /// <returns>JObject value</returns>
    public static async Task<JObject> GetUserInfos(string accessToken)
    {
        JObject json = null;
        Uri uri = new Uri($"https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token={accessToken}");

        System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage result = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
        //user info returnd as JSON
        string jsonUserInfo = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        if (jsonUserInfo != null)
        {
            json = JObject.Parse(jsonUserInfo);
            //username = json["name"].ToString();
            //email = json["emails"]["account"].ToString();
        }
        return json;
    }
```

And because the OneDrive method never expires if the token is no longer usable :

```
    bool WaitForODConnectionExecuted = false;
    private async Task WaitForODConnection(MsaAuthenticationProvider msaAuthProvider)
    {
        await msaAuthProvider.RestoreMostRecentFromCacheOrAuthenticateUserAsync();
        WaitForODConnectionExecuted = true;
    }
```

It was not funny and I think my code is not clean so do not use it as it is without working a little on it.

Comment: Explain your suggestion.

Comment: If the last known connection token is usable, this method can be used to authenticate the user without prompt it.
So, this restore the last authentication cache if it can or prompt the user to give his login and password.

This can replace the already used `AuthenticateUserAsync` method.

I had the same issue and this method solved it.

Comment: OK. Add this to your answer, so that it can be helpful to others. Comments can be deleted, but answers remain.

Comment: initially my comment was a question, but hey ... Done.

Comment: You want that your answer is useful to people who have similar problem, don't you? :)

Comment: Yes I want, but I'm not really satisfied by my code so I don't think others will be.
It need to be improved.